# Click Event Triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following structure in my HTML :

```
@if(some_condition)
<div id="SomeDiv">
  @include('first_view')
</div>

@elseif(some_other_condition)
<div id="SomeDiv">
  @include('second_view')
</div>
@endif
```

And, I have a click event which is supposed to be triggered when a **'td'** inside the `'first_view'` or `'second_view'` is clicked as :

```
$('#SomeDiv").on("click",'td',function(){
  console.log("Hello");
});
```

I have a feature where I need to switch between `'first_view'` and `'second_view'`. Which I do using ajax to load the views as :

```
$('#switchBtn').on('click',function(){
   var _url = $(this).data('url');
   $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:_url,
      success:function(response){
       /* Response contains the views as html string */
       response = JSON.parse(response);
       $('#SomeDiv').empty();
       $('#SomeDiv').html(response['response']);
      }
    });
});
```

**The Problem :**

The Clicked event is triggered two times on first load. i.e the "Hello" is printed twice. And each time i switch between the views and trigger the click event it is triggered one more times than the previous time.

i.e. On first load the "Hello" is printed twice, after i switch views, the "Hello" is printed thrice and so on.

Can somebody tell what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems that I see:

1. Your HTML output two different things using `if` but not `else` to make them exclusive. They could both happen at the same time.
2. The code to register the `click` event is executed every time the HTML is rendered (maybe because it is inside `SomeDiv`), so when you do `$('#SomeDiv').html(response['response']);` it rendered HTML and execute the register again. Meanings you have 3 global listeners -> print 3 times.

To fix this, you need to move the code to register `click` event outside of `SomeDiv` (I suggest put them into a `something.js` and put them at the end of the page).

Comment: I have modified the condition inside a if else if endif as you suggested and moved my javascript to scripts.js file which is loaded in the main template. It's still the same. I implemented the answer by @Shree as well to no avail.

Comment: I am accepting this answer although this is not the complete solution to my problem but somehow guided me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `off()` to remove previous handlers attached .Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.

So in your case:

```
$("#SomeDiv").off().on("click","td",function(){
  console.log("Hello");
});
```